# why UserFullname cant be retrieve by xml parser?

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

this is the web service method and the info retrieved...
[image: method SOAP 1.1]

[image: method HTTP POST]

[image: data retrieved]

why cant the string of words in UserFullname cant be retrieved?

xmlparsing in xcode:

```
        //connect to webservice
    NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                         "<soap:Body>"
                         "<RetrieveUser xmlns=\"http://dev.cel.nie.edu.sg/\">"
                         "<password>%@</password>"
                         "</RetrieveUser>"
                         "</soap:Body>"
                         "</soap:Envelope>", passWordField.text];


    //requesting
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.cel.nie.edu.sg/projects/VideoApp/VideoWebService.asmx"]];
    //message length??
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

    //building the post xml
    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:@"http://dev.cel.nie.edu.sg/RetrieveUser" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //connection
    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    //[req release];
    if(conn){
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    }




        -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
[webData setLength:0];


        }

        -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
[webData appendData:data];

        }

        -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
[conn release];
[webData release];

NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please connect to the internet to continue."];

UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
[errorAlert release];
        }

        -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{


xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[xmlParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[xmlParser parse];

[conn release];
[webData release];
        }

        -(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
        }

        -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

//retrieve lecturer's ID, name and photo according to the password. Retrieve from web service

currentElement = [elementName copy];
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"UserID"]) {
    // clear out our story item caches...
    currentID = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    lectFullName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentImg = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

}

        }

        -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
// save the characters for the current item...
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"UserID"]) {
    [currentID appendString:string];

}else if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"Username"]){
    [currentName appendString:string];
    NSLog(@"lect username: %@", currentName);


}else if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"UserFullname"]){
    [lectFullName appendString:string];
    NSLog(@"lectname: %@", lectFullName);

}else if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"UserImage"]){
    [currentImg appendString:string];
    NSLog(@"lect img: %@", currentImg);

}

        }


        -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

        }
```

Output:

```
        2011-11-04 16:45:16.314 MyLauncher[4538:707] lect username: tom
        2011-11-04 16:45:16.317 MyLauncher[4538:707] lect img: http://dev.cel.nie.edu.sg/projects/VideoApp/LecturerImages/ID2--DaPe--2011-11-03-Ti7e--04-07-38.jpg
```

i just dont understand y its not retrieving the data string for UserFullname... is there some error in my codes or something? thx for ur help...

Comment: Fix a breakpoint inside that else if loop and check whether the control reaches there.

Comment: ok i found out that the asmx file I updated and place it into my ftp server.. but is not reading the updated file..its still recognising only the old one... hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it... in the ftp server i not only need to add the webservice .asmx file but in the ftp http docs folder I have to put the webservice .dll and .pbd files into the bin folder...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with a single token for UserFullName. (e.g. "Tom")

Is it possibly something to do with the  not being encoded properly ?

Comment: hi, yes i tried with a single token UserFullname also but it does not work too... i did not understand about 'not being encoded properly' what do you mean by that?